# Is this a design pattern - returning this from setters?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is there a name for this:

```
class A
{
   A* setA() 
   {
       //set a
       return this; 
   }
   A* setB()
   {
       //set b
       return this;
   }
};
```

so you can do something like this:

```
A* a = new A;
a->setA()->setB();
```

Are there any drawbacks to using this? Advantages?

Comment: Main drawback is that you could be returning `*this` as an `A&`, and writing `A* a = new A; a->setA().setB()` or (more importantly) `A b; b.setA().setB();`. `b.setA()->setB();` is a bit rubbish ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's known as **method chaining** ([FAQ link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.4)), and is more commonly done with references, not pointers.

Method chaining is strongly associated with the **Named Parameter Idiom** ([FAQ link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20)), as I now, after posting an initial version of this answer, see that [Steve Jessop discusses in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149896/is-this-a-design-pattern-returning-this-from-setters/8150104#8150104). The NPI idiom is one simple way to provide a large number of defaulted arguments without forcing complexity into the constructor calls. For example, this is relevant for GUI programming.

One potential problem with the method chaining technique is when you want or need to apply the NPI idiom for classes in an inheritance hierarchy. Then you discover that C++ does not support **covariant methods**. What that is: when you let your eyes wander up or down the classes in a chain of class inheritance, then a covariant method is one whose definition involves some type that to your wandering eye varies in specificity in the same way as the class it’s defined in.

It is about the same problem as with defining a `clone` method, which has the same textual definition in all classes, but must be laboriously repeated in each class in order to get the types right.

Solving that problem is hard without language support; it appears to be an inherently complex problem, a kind of conflict with the C++ type system. My [“How to do typed optional arguments in C++98” blog post](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/cppx-how-to-do-typed-optional-arguments-in-c98/) links to relevant source code for automating the generation of covariant definitions, and to an article I wrote about it in Dr. Dobbs Journal. Maybe I'll revisit that for C++11, or sometime, because the complexity and possible brittleness may appear as a larger cost than it’s worth…

Comment: The FAQ links here should be updated to ISO CPP. I incorrectly rejected someone's edit to do that. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249938/i-incorrectly-rejected-some-edits-what-to-do)

Answer (score 4):

I've heard it called something like "[method chaining](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining)" before, but I wouldn't call it a design pattern. (Some people also talk about implementing a "[fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.2B.2B)" using this - I'd never seen it called that before though, but [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) seems to have written about it a while back)

You don't lose much by doing this - you can always ignore the return result quite happily if you don't want to use it like that.

As to is it worth doing I'm less sure. It can be quite cryptic in some circumstances. It is however basically *required* for things like `operator<<` for stream based IO though. I'd say it's a call to be made on how it fits in with the rest of the code - is it expected/obvious to people reading it?

(As Steve Jessop pointed out this is almost always done with references though, not pointers)

Answer (score 3):

Another common-ish use is with "parameter objects". Without method chaining, they're quite inconvenient to set up, but with it they can be temporaries.

Instead of:

```
complicated_function(P1 param1 = default1, P2 param2 = default2, P3 param3 = default3);
```

Write:

```
struct ComplicatedParams {
    P1 mparam1;
    P2 mparam2;
    P3 mparam3;
    ComplicatedParams() : mparam1(default1), mparam2(default2), mparam3(default3) {}
    ComplicatedParams &param1(P1 p) { mparam1 = p; return *this; }
    ComplicatedParams &param2(P2 p) { mparam2 = p; return *this; }
    ComplicatedParams &param3(P3 p) { mparam3 = p; return *this; }
};

complicated_function(const ComplicatedParams &params);
```

Now I can call it:

```
complicated_function(ComplicatedParams().param2(foo).param1(bar));
```

Which means the caller doesn't have to remember the order of parameters. Without the method chaining that would have to be:

```
ComplicatedParams params;
params.param1(foo);
params.param2(bar);
complicated_function(params);
```

I can also call it:

```
complicated_function(ComplicatedParams().param3(baz));
```

Which means that without having to define a tonne of overloads, I can specify just the last parameter and leave the rest at default.

The final obvious tweak is to make `complicated_function` a member of `ComplicatedParams`:

```
struct ComplicatedAction {
    P1 mparam1;
    P2 mparam2;
    P3 mparam3;
    ComplicatedAction() : mparam1(default1), mparam2(default2), mparam3(default3) {}
    ComplicatedAction &param1(P1 p) { mparam1 = p; return *this; }
    ComplicatedAction &param2(P2 p) { mparam2 = p; return *this; }
    ComplicatedAction &param3(P3 p) { mparam3 = p; return *this; }
    run(void);
};

ComplicatedAction().param3(baz).run();
```

Answer (score 2):

One downside is that if you derive a class from A, say like this:

```
class Foo : public A
{
public:
  Foo *setC()
  {
    // set C
    return this;
  }
};
```

then the order you call the setters is important. You'll need to call all the setters on Foo first: For example, this won't work:

```
Foo f=new Foo();
f->setA()->setC();
```

Whereas this will:

```
Foo f=new Foo();
f->setC()->setA();
```

Comment: Good point - this is why it's not possible to write something like `(std::ostringstream() << "hi" << 0).str()` which would be a very handy idiom if it worked.

Comment: @awoodland: can you cook up something like `template <typename T> std::ostringstream &operator<<(std::ostringstream &o, const T &t) { static_cast<std::ostream &>(o) << t; return o; }`, or is that template a less good match than the existing function with `ostream&`?

Comment: @SteveJessop - A derived type would be a better match than a base type, but it doesn't seem to work when I tried it just now. I'll try and figure out why.

Comment: @SteveJessop - there's two problems with that I think. Firstly it's a non-const reference for `operator<<`, but `std::ostringstream()` makes a temporary which can't be bound to the non-const reference. Secondly I think there are `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, int);` and one for `const char*` which don't have any template parameters so would still be a better match I think.

Comment: @awoodland: that was my worry, that the plain function beats the template even though the derived reference beats the base class reference.

Comment: @SteveJessop - with C++11's rvalue references and move semantics it appears to work though - `template <typename T>
std::ostringstream&& operator<<(std::ostringstream&& out, const T& t) {
  static_cast<std::ostream&>(out) << t;
  return std::move(out);
}` compiles and does exactly what you'd hope. The "usual" `operator<<` for these *is* a template - it takes `basic_ostream<char_type>`, not just `ostream`, so it can work and it was only the reference to temporary breaking it before.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I think the C++11 version of this is interesting enough that I've asked a [question over on code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/a-version-of-operator-that-returns-ostringstream-instead-of-ostream) about it before these comments get too far off track

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly used in for example Boost, but most of the time the functions returns references instead:

```
A &setX()
{
    // ...
    return *this;
}
```